# How to make this SQL SELECT?

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2012

i cant figure out how to make this comparison select for both years for every plant.

```
SELECT PlantName, SUM(Amount) AS Amount_Harvested_2014 
FROM Harvest
WHERE year=2014
GROUP BY PlantName
```

In the desired output a row should look like this:

```
PlantName  2014Amount  2015Amount  2015-2014Amount
```

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE Harvest(
 harvest_id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
 PlantName nvarchar(20) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Plants(PlantName),
 Amount int NOT NULL,
 year int,
 harvester_id int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Workers(Worker_ID)
)
```

And the example content of the table:

```
harvest_id  PlantName   Amount  year    harvester_id
1           Rose        32      2015    2
2           Rose        12      2015    5
```

Comment: Yes ms sql server 2012

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to do this (which might not be the best) is to use conditional aggregation like this:

```
select 
    PlantName
    ,sum(case when year=2014 then Amount else 0 end) as "2014amount"
    ,sum(case when year=2015 then Amount else 0 end) as "2015amount"
    ,sum(case when year=2015 then Amount else 0 end) - sum(case when year=2014 then Amount else 0 end) as "2015-2014Amount"
from harvest
group by plantname
```

Comment: Thanks, but some other method would be better :) Some kind of JOINS or something?

Comment: @user3687719 I don't really think using joins would be simpler, but take a look at this if you want to see a solution based on joins: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/32bbf/1

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this would be by using the `pivot` option in SQL server:

```
select *, [2015] -[2014] as '2015-1014'
from 
(
  select PlantName, year, Amount
  from Harvest
) src
pivot
(
  sum(Amount)
  for year in ([2014], [2015])
) piv;
```

Which would give the following output:

PlantName   2014    2015    2015-1014

Apple          2    15       13

Rose          11    44       33

This would also allow for easier updates if more years history was added.